# What is this 5-pronged electrical outlet attached to the alternator used for?

Tags: electrical, electronics

I have the below hookup right next to the engine (CAT 3116) and I'm not sure what it is for. I tried googling this, but didn't find a hookup that was similar. The approximate circumference of the red connector is about 3 inches.

- What is it for and what voltage, amperage is it rated for?
- What is the pinout?

[image]

Comment: Without seeing what it's attached to, I'm betting it's a connection for an engine heater. No clue about the pinout. ... and I could also be wrong, heh.

Comment: Instead of googling that connector, try the website for the machine manufacturer, they will usually specify the (optional) equipment... Was this original equipment?

Comment: Since it is a male connector with exposed pins, I would have thought it was an input rather than a power output.  Could it be a remote engine start connector?